# Can I set an exact location of an object using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, coordinates, tkinter-canvas

Using Python3.7 I have created code that will move a ball from the top left corner to the bottom right corner. I am using coords to position the ball and move for the motion of the ball. However, I want the ball to start in a certin place. How can I set the position of the ball?

1. I have tried using place function and I get the error: 'int' object has no attribute 'place'
2. I tried using coords and I get the error: IndexError: list index out of range
3. I have tried changing my create_oval code. It works for the size of the ball but not where it starts from.

The code here works with no errors. How and where should I have a line for the exact coordinates of where the ball will start.

```
import tkinter as tkr
import time
tk = tkr.Tk()
canvas = tkr.Canvas(tk, width=480, height=480)
canvas.grid()
ball = canvas.create_oval(10,10,20,20,fill="blue")
x = 1
y = 1
while True:
    canvas.move(ball,x,y)
    pos = canvas.coords(ball)
    if pos [3] >= 480 or pos[1] <=0:
        y = -y
    if pos[2] >= 480 or pos[0] <= 0:
        x = -x
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.0099)
    pass
tk.mainloop()
```

Also if I can get rid of the deprecation warning, that would be great as well.

Comment: Why number 3 not working? It is the correct way to set the starting position.

Answer (score 2):

Used variables with the create_oval.

```
import tkinter as tkr
import time
tk = tkr.Tk()
canvas = tkr.Canvas(tk, width=480, height=480)
canvas.grid()
x = 47
y = 185
ball = canvas.create_oval(x,y,x+10,y+10,fill="blue")

dx = 1
dy = 1

while True:
    canvas.move(ball,dx,dy)
    pos = canvas.coords(ball)
    if pos [3] >= 480 or pos[1] <=0:
        dy = -dy
    if pos[2] >= 480 or pos[0] <= 0:
        dx = -dx
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.0099)
    pass
tk.mainloop()
```

Big thanks to Tim Roberts. I end up taking his coding advice and edit mine original code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do a loop like this within the confines of an event-driven UI framework.  Each callback does one little bit of work, then goes back to the loop to wait for future events.

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
win = tk.Tk()
canvas = tk.Canvas(win, width=480, height=480)
canvas.grid()
x = 10
y = 10
dx = 1
dy = 1

def moveball():
    global x, dx
    global y, dy
    x += dx
    y += dy
    canvas.move(ball,dx,dy)
    if y >= 480 or y <=0:
        dy = -dy
    if x >= 480 or x <= 0:
        dx = -dx
    win.after( 10, moveball )

ball = canvas.create_oval(x,y,x+10,y+10,fill="blue")
win.after( 100, moveball )
win.mainloop()
```

You'll note that the ball doesn't change directions until after it's all the way off the edge of the screen.  That's because we're tracking the upper left corner of the ball and not taking the size into account.  That's an easy thing to fix.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But I am not sure where to add this line. As I have tried replacing the code in a few places all with errors. One of the erorrs is: 
TypeError: itemconfigure() takes from 2 to 3 positional arguments but 4 were given. Which makes me think it is trying to pull the numbers from the "ball=" line.
When I enter the new code for the the "pos=" line it get a different error.
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-x"

Comment: If you have `canvas.move` working, then you don't need this answer.  I'll go back to commenting on the main question.

Comment: Thank you again. Your new code seems to give me the same result as the original code I entered. I want to have the ball start in a different place other than the upper left corner. Like maybe the lower left or center by having somewhere state x=0,y=5, or something similar.

Comment: You do see that the initial coordinates are set by the statements `x=10` and `y=10`, right?  If you want `x=0` and `y=5`, then that's exactly what you should use.

Comment: I do and it does not change the starting position. Do it change if for you? For me, no matter what I enter it always starts in the upper left corner. What does change is the size of the ball. All the changes I tried with my code and your code, either changes the size of the ball or the speed. None change the starting position from the upper left corner.

Comment: OK, I didn't notice that `create_oval` wants x0,y0,x1,y1 instead of x,y,w,h.  The "size of the ball" thing should have been a clue.  One minor change to the source.